# Gerador de números aleatórios com restrições

Tags: r

Preciso definir aleatoriamente o peso que de uma carteira de investimentos que é divido em três tipos e cm as seguintes limitações:

1. Renda Fixa [0-100%]
2. Renda Variável [0-30%]
3. Investimento no Exterior 0-10%]

Restrições:

1. Todos os investimentos devem ser maior ou igual 0;
2. E a soma dos pesos deve ser 1 + 2 + 3 = 100%.

Gerar os números em separado não é o problema e obedecer a primeira restrição é fácil, mas não consigo fazer a segunda.

```
rendaFixa <- runif(1, 0, 1)
rendaVariavel <- runif(1, 0, 0.3)
rendaIE <- runif(1, 0, 0.1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu sortearia primeiro os valores de `rendaIE` e `rendaVariavel`. Da maneira como essas proporções estão definidas, as suas somas nunca ultrapassarão 40%. A partir daí, `rendaFixa` seria a diferença entre 100% e a soma `rendaIE + rendaVariavel`. Computacionalmente, seria algo assim:

```r
set.seed(1)

rendaIE <- runif(1, 0, 0.1)
rendaVariavel <- runif(1, 0, 0.3)
rendaFixa <- 1 - rendaIE - rendaVariavel

rendaIE
#> [1] 0.02655087
rendaVariavel
#> [1] 0.1116372
rendaFixa
#> [1] 0.861812

rendaIE + rendaVariavel + rendaFixa
#> [1] 1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>